# How to keep a maximum count of ten values in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Everytime the user visit a page, the page url will be stored into an array session. I want to have 10 elements in the array only. So that 10 elements will save 10 latest visited page urls. Here is my codes :

```
if (empty($_SESSION['page'])) {
     $_SESSION['page'] = array_fill(0,10,'');
 }

 function trackPage($url) {
     array_unshift($_SESSION['page'],$url);
    array_pop($_SESSION['page']);
 }


trackPage($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

and also tell mw how to write

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that your code is missing is session_start(), ie:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['page'])) {
     $_SESSION['page'] = array_fill(0,10,'');
 }

 function trackPage($url) {
     array_unshift($_SESSION['page'],$url);
    array_pop($_SESSION['page']);
 }


trackPage($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

var_dump($_SESSION['page']);

?>
```

I only added the var_dump to moniter the session information.

Answer (score 0):

I added if(array_search($url, $_SESSION['page'])=== false) this code to avoid duplicate entries multiple times

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['page'])) {
     $_SESSION['page'] = array_fill(0,10,'');
 }

 function trackPage($url) {
     if(array_search($url, $_SESSION['page'])=== false){
         array_unshift($_SESSION['page'],$url);
        array_pop($_SESSION['page']);
     }
 }


trackPage($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

var_dump($_SESSION['page']);
```